# how do I pass a parameter using url.action in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    function myFunction(val) {
        var myValue = val;
        location.href = '@Url.Action("ScanningWifi", "Devices" , new { meterData = "meterData" })';

    }
</script>
```

what I would like to do is pass "myValue" to my action

Comment: Pass it the same way you are passing meterData

Comment: it won't seem to recognize it

Comment: I get an error : CS0103: The name 'myValue' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Can you post the action method signature?

Comment: you mean using Ajax?

Comment: No, I am talking about the action method you are passing the value to. Post the action method signature in your controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159095/discussion-between-paul-t-rykiel-and-the-outsider).

Comment: `location.href = '@Url.Action(...})' + '&yourParameterName =' + myValue;`  (assuming `meterData` is added as a query string value.